# What is between local buffer and return address on stack?

Tags: c, stack, gdb

I have one local char buffer size 4 that I fill with strcpy of the main argv[1] that has 4 'A' characters. Using gdb I print out my variable and stack information. I then examine the memory contents.

```
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0xbffff0e0:
eip = 0x804848e in main (sbov.c:12); saved eip = 0xb7e2fa83
source language c.
Arglist at 0xbffff0d8, args: argc=2, argv=0xbffff174
Locals at 0xbffff0d8, Previous frame's sp is 0xbffff0e0
Saved registers:
ebp at 0xbffff0d8, eip at 0xbffff0dc
(gdb) print &buffer
$8 = (char (*)[1]) 0xbffff0cf
(gdb) x/5xw 0xbffff0cf
0xbffff0cf: 0x41414141  0x00000000  0x00000000  0xe2fa8300
0xbffff0df: 0x000002b7
(gdb) x/32xb 0xbffff0cf
0xbffff0cf: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0xbffff0d7: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x83    0xfa    0xe2
0xbffff0df: 0xb7    0x02    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x74    0xf1    0xff
0xbffff0e7: 0xbf    0x80    0xf1    0xff    0xbf    0xea    0xcc    0xfe
```

After the last 0x41 and before 0x83, what are the 0x00's? Is this just extra space?

Source Code

```
/* sbov.c */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc > 1) {
        char buffer[4];
        strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
        fprintf(stdout, "echo: %s\n", buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler Options

```
gcc -ggdb -fno-stack-protector
```

Yes this is for a security class, it is vulnerable to stack overflow on purpose.

Comment: Please provide your code and any infromation about compiller options.

Comment: "...so the saved eip (return address is backwards)...". Er... backwards? You are using word-by-word format to display your memory. Nothing is backwards there. If you displayed it byte-by-byte, then it would have been backwards, but not in your case. Judging by your output, your words are misaligned and don't match the natural word boundary. That's is why part of the return address suddenly "jumped" to another word.

Comment: @AnT I examined using bytes and it is better aligned that way. Still wondering what the empty space is between the buffer and the return address?

Comment: "I fill with strcpy of the main argv[1] that has 4 'A' characters." --> not quite.  `strcpy()` copies 4 `A` characters and attempts to write a null character too.  Memory dump of that 5th byte may/may not reflect the value that was there or the true value that was attempted to be written.  It is UB after all.

Comment: @chux - ok that makes sense. I'll take a look.